# cocoapods: library not found for

Tags: ios, cocoapods

> ld: library not found for -l<libname>
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

I have got a such problem.
I've created a project in one Mac. But when I move project to another computer and try to add a new library from cocoapod the linker cannot find a new library.

I've tried a lot of features:

1. recreated via `pod init`.
2. `pod update`
3. cleared cache

   ```
   rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
   rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
   pod update
   ```
4. Even reinstalled cocoapods.
5. removed old workspace file.
6. etc.

But none of them helped me. Please, help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hours later I found that I have to use `$(inherit)` flag for 'Library Search Path' . I do not know why it worked in the first computer without with flag.

Comment: It should most likely be `$(inherited)`