# Cocoapods : Library Not found Repeated

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an iOS project that has used cocoapods successfully for a few years.

My macbook screen died so I have cloned it to a new macbook temporarily and can no longer build the project. I get a warning for every pod I use along the lines of:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bloc-dwchsantxfnowlfgcxthlhtnypue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AWSCognito'
```

and an error on the first one:

```
ld: library not found for -lAWSCognito
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I realise that there are several question similar to this but I have tried most of the answers including: quitting XCode, cleaning the project, pod update, pod install, pod deintegrate, checked I have the latest cocoapods, tried the beta version of cocoapods then reverted to the latest release (1.5.3) (repeated all the above many times in various combinations).

I have done pod init, and the correct target was put in the podfile.

I always launch XCode by double clicking the .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj file

I have checked that $(inherited) is in the 'Library Search Path' as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710584/cocoapods-library-not-found-for) (though the problem is actually that the libraries are not being generated in the correct place as oppose to not being found there - in fact I dont believe they are being generated at all).

I have deleted the -lPods-Projectname.a under the Frameworks group as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691503/xcode-cocoapods-library-not-found-error) (it was red...)

As per [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405325/cocoapods-library-not-found?lq=1) I have:

`rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`

then moved my project.xcworkspace to a backup location, reinstalled cocoapods, `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`

A curious fact was that having had cocoapods generate the new workspace there was not a scheme for the project (the only scheme on the new macbook was for a library that has been manually added).

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Bloc' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for Bloc

    pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
    #pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
    pod 'UIView+TKGeometry'
    pod 'Branch'
    pod 'AWSCognito'
    pod 'AWSDynamoDB' 
    pod 'AWSS3'
    pod 'Firebase/Core' #, '~> 4.13.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
    pod 'TwitterKit', '<3.3.0' # probably 3.2.2
    pod 'TwitterCore', '<3.1.0' # probably 3.0.3
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'QBImagePickerController' 
    pod 'SDWebImage'

    post_install do |installer|
         installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
            end
         end
     end    
 end
```

Realising that the problem is the pods not being built, I have looked at my Target Dependencies - there are 0 items. When I attempt to add a dependency there are no pod related ones to add. If I look at the Pods target, it also has 0 dependencies. Here I could add dependencies so selected all the pod library .a files for the libPods-Bloc.a target. I then made a new scheme for libPods-Bloc.a and built it  and all the libraries I need were built in the correct place. However I still am unable to add anything to my projects target dependencies to automate building the pods (ie I cant drag the libPods-Bloc.a and it is not in the list to select). libPods-Bloc.a is however in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries

However this does not work fully (and obviously is not a good solution) - the libraries get built and included in my target but I then get a 'Invalid bitcode signature' link error. I have Enable Bitcode set to 0 and my Deployment target is 9.0 and I have the loop in the podfile to set the deployment target to 9.0 for each pod which sorted this problem sometime back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have finally found the solution, thanks to answers in [this question](http://Cocoapods%20ld:%20library%20not%20found%20for%20-lPods-Projectname). I had read the accepted answer there, but the vital info was in several other answers which I didnt see until desperately reading everything I could find on the subject.

The problem is ensuring that the `Build Active Architectures Only` settings are the same for the Pods target and the project target. It is sensible to have debug -> Yes, but important to have release-> No. Its okay to have the debug different from the release. In my case the Pods was set to Yes for both. This is presumably a cocoapods default and really should be considered a bug.

This somehow fixed all my problems. I'm not sure how it fixed the dependency one - but all libraries are built when necessary and I also dont have the 'Invalid bitcode signature' error which is understandable.